# Download multiple files with Javascript, and watch progression

Tags: javascript, download

I code in Javascript. I have a table in which I have a list of links that I would like to download and put together in a zip.
Everything works fine, but I would like each file to download one by one, and to make a console.log each time a file is finished.
For now, the code I have allows me to download everything, but everything is downloaded at once, and the console.logs arrive all together. I would like to be able to follow the progress in the console.log.

```
function downloadFiles(urls) {
    let zip = new JSZip();
    let count = urls.length;
    let promises = [];

    function downloadFile(url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            console.log("Downloading file " + url.split('/').pop());

            JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    zip.file(url.split('/').pop(), data, { binary: true });
                    console.log("The file " + url.split('/').pop() + " has been downloaded");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        promises.push(downloadFile(url));
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log("Download complete");
        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
            saveAs(content, "Fichiers.zip");
        });
    });
}

function main() {
    allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    hrefs  = []; // Ici, récupérer l'ensemble des pdfs
    for (let i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
        if (allLinks[i].href.substr(-4) == ".pdf") {
            hrefs.push(allLinks[i].href);
        }
    }
    downloadFiles(hrefs);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a nifty array method I import in a lot of projects called 'asyncForEach'. It basically is a forEach that expects the iterating function to be a promise and waits for the promise to be resolved before continuing to the next index...

```js
Array.prototype.asyncForEach = async function(func) {
    var i = 0
    var length = this.length
    var funcs = []
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        this.forEach((...args) => {
            funcs.push(func.bind(this, ...args))
        })

        async function loop() {
            await funcs[i]()
            i++
            if (i == length) {
                res()
            } else {
                loop()
            }
        }
        loop()
    })
}
```

So it makes a binded function where the arg is each iteration of the forEach function then loops through all the functions in that array asynchronously! For your use case, the usage should be something like this

```js
/* Replace these lines:
         urls.forEach(function (url) {
        promises.push(downloadFile(url));
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log("Download complete");
        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
            saveAs(content, "Fichiers.zip");
        });
    });
*/

    urls.asyncForEach(downloadFile).then(function () {
        console.log("Download complete");
        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
            saveAs(content, "Fichiers.zip");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, it works as intended !